# npm install @atom/watcher and dump message

Tags: node.js, npm

If I run `npm install`, it will throws me a ton of messages that I don't understand originated from `@atom/watcher` I think.

```
$ npm install

> @atom/watcher@1.0.3 install /home/vdegenne/Gits/node/github-fetch-starter/node_modules/@atom/watcher
> node --harmony script/helper/gen-compilation-db.js rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/vdegenne/Gits/node/github-fetch-starter/node_modules/@atom/watcher/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/binding.o
In file included from ../../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/binding.cpp:2:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ is deprecated: Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 bj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/binding.cpp:2:
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3165:29: note: declared here
                 Maybe<bool> ForceSet(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key,
                             ^
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/hub.o
In file included from ../../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/hub.cpp:3:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ is deprecated: Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 bj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/hub.cpp:3:
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3165:29: note: declared here
                 Maybe<bool> ForceSet(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key,
                             ^
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/log.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/errable.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/queue.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/lock.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/message.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/message_buffer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/thread_starter.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/thread.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/status.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/worker_thread.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/recent_file_cache.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/polling/directory_record.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/polling/polled_root.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/polling/polling_iterator.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/polling/polling_thread.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/helper/libuv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/nan/all_callback.o
In file included from ../../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/nan/all_callback.cpp:3:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ is deprecated: Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 bj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/nan/all_callback.cpp:3:
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3165:29: note: declared here
                 Maybe<bool> ForceSet(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key,
                             ^
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/nan/functional_callback.o
In file included from ../../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/nan/functional_callback.cpp:3:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ is deprecated: Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 bj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/nan/functional_callback.cpp:3:
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3165:29: note: declared here
                 Maybe<bool> ForceSet(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key,
                             ^
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/nan/options.o
In file included from ../../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/nan/options.cpp:1:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:73: warning: ‘v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ is deprecated: Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 bj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../../nan/nan.h:49,
                 from ../src/nan/options.cpp:1:
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8.h:3165:29: note: declared here
                 Maybe<bool> ForceSet(Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key,
                             ^
/home/vdegenne/.node-gyp/9.10.1/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/helper/common_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/linux/pipe.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/linux/side_effect.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/linux/cookie_jar.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/linux/watched_directory.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/linux/watch_registry.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watcher/src/worker/linux/linux_worker_platform.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/watcher.node
  COPY Release/watcher.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/vdegenne/Gits/node/github-fetch-starter/node_modules/@atom/watcher/build'
npm WARN prepublish-on-install As of npm@5, `prepublish` scripts are deprecated.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install Use `prepare` for build steps and `prepublishOnly` for upload-only.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install See the deprecation note in `npm help scripts` for more information.

> github-fetch-starter@1.0.0 prepublish /home/vdegenne/Gits/node/github-fetch-starter
> npm run build


> github-fetch-starter@1.0.0 build /home/vdegenne/Gits/node/github-fetch-starter
> tsc

npm WARN github-fetch-starter@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 192 packages from 483 contributors in 21.847s
```

Why are those messages, how can I prevent this ? I never saw these messages before but I can't know what I did wrong, if I did something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are warnings from compiling the C++ in the `@atom/watcher` package. It doesn't fail to install so it's safe to say that you can ignore them.

I tried `npm install @atom/watcher` and the exit status was 0 - `echo $?` - so successfully installed.